# Installing Ubuntu 13.04 on Ideapad u510 after deleting all partitions

Tags: system-installation

Here is my problem.  I purchased a lenovo ideapad u510.  I switched the boot mode to legacy, started the ubuntu live cd (via usb), deleted all partions on the 24gb ssd as well as the 500gb hdd and started installing ubuntu.  That's what I always do, because I like to start with fresh partition tables when I install an operating system.  But this time I ran into serious trouble.  The hdd just doesn't play along.  For some reason I had to install everything on /dev/sda, which is the 24gb ssd.  I did create a partition on /dev/sdb (for /home) but couldn't use it.  I don't remember what the problem was.

Well, the installation was successful.  Since than a message kept popping up all the time, telling me about a defect hard drive.  I deleted from /dev/sdb1 (partition on the 500gb hdd) and the message didn't show up anymore.  But still, I am stuck with a system of just 24gb in total of external memory, although there is a 500gb hard drive in that machine.  It is there in /dev/ as /dev/sdb, but `gparted /dev/sdb` now gives me the message "Error opening /dev/sdb: no medium found".

Apparently the ssd and hdd are supposed to work together in some kind of raid-like fashion.  Unfortunately I screwed that up when I deleted all the original partitions.  I know nothing about this stuff and Ubuntu doesn't either.  Does anyone know how to fix this?  i just want to have Ubuntu on that machine and be able to use both disks.

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

The hdd did not work because the sata cable was not properly connected to the board.  I must have ripped it out while replacing the hdd.  I did not mention that I replaced it to see if maybe that is the problem.  The little plug was just halfway connected, that is why the system could see /dev/sdb but not access it.

So basically the only important thing is to disable intel rapid start in bios setup.  After that, the ssd and hdd are just two regular devices and ubuntu can be installed and used as usual.